# React native firebase authentication using different providers

Tags: javascript, react-native, firebase-authentication, react-native-firebase

Firstly I create new user in firebase using function `createUserWithEmailAndPassword(jamesdmurphy51@gmail.com, password)`.

I then sign in using Facebook using the code below

```
const result = await LoginManager.logInWithPermissions(['public_profile', 'email']);
const data = await AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken();
const firebaseCredential = await auth.FacebookAuthProvider.credential(data.accessToken);
const fbUserObj = await auth().signInWithCredential(firebaseCredential);
```

Problem is that it creates a completely seperate user account with seperate UID....even though the email address linked to the facebook account is the same one that was used to `createUserWithEmailAndPassword`.
How do I make it so user can log into exising account using Facebook?

Comment: When I used firebase, that code worked exactly fine for me

Comment: I think you're looking for a way to merge two accounts with a same email. This question has been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40951272/9957187). Additionally, you can check the Firebase [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/account-linking) for auth merge (this is for web though, might work differently in React Native).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you call `auth().signInWithCredential(firebaseCredential)`, you're indeed creating a new account in Firebase Authentication.

If you instead want to link the Facebook credentials to an existing account, you need to call `linkWithPopup` or `linkWithRedirect` as shown in the Firebase documentation on [linking accounts](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/account-linking#link-federated-auth-provider-credentials-to-a-user-account).

Comment: The link provided is not applicable if youre using @react-native-firebase like I am

Comment: Bit of a necro, but to anyone who came here looking for the same thing (or you @jamesmurphy ) I did, my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69671161/how-do-i-use-saml-to-authenticate-a-user-in-firebase-under-react-native-expo/69671162#69671162) might be helpful.